# How access JSON object serialized by Django

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, django

I'm not able to access primary key of an object serialized by Django in JSON. My JavaScript looks like:

```js
function makeLink() {
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
        let fd = new FormData;
        fd.append("audio", blob);
        let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                /*console.log(obj[0].pk);*/
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = obj.data[0]['pk'];
            }
        }

        xhr.open('POST', uploadAudio_url , true)
        //alert(uploadAudio_url)
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            // __log("Audio Uploaded to server succesfully");
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            // __log("Error Uploading audio" + e)
        };

        xhr.send(fd);
    });

}
```

I send the blob data which it is an audio file in order to process speech in the backend. The backend process the audio file and filter the objects properly. Then it response to the client with a queryset in JSON. I have interested in get the objects PK and show images in a gallery grid.

This is my

### Views.py:

```
def process_speech(recognized_audio):
    speech = recognized_audio
    url = ''  # Is the URL where the user will be redirected once speech is proccessed
    keylist = []
    for key in Keyword.objects.all():
        if(speech.find(key.keyword.lower()) != -1):
            keylist.append(key.keyword)

    print('Identificado Keyword: ', keylist)
    if (speech.find('fotos') != -1 or speech.find('fotografías') != -1):
        print("Reconocido FOTO")
        imagenes_filtered = Imagen.objects.filter(keyword__keyword__in=keylist)
        #print(imagenes_filtered)
        return imagenes_filtered
    if (speech.find('video') != -1):
        print("Reconocido VIDEO")

def upload(request):
    print("Método: ", request.method)
    print("Ajax: ", request.is_ajax())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.FILES.get('audio'):
            record_audio = request.FILES['audio']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(record_audio.name + ".wav", record_audio)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
            print("File received succesfully")
            speech = decodeSpeech(filename)
            print(speech)
            objects = process_speech(speech)
            data = serializers.serialize('json', objects)
            return HttpResponse(JsonResponse({'data': data}, safe=False),)
        else:
            return render_to_response('index.html', {"errors":"No recognized audio"})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
```

The Json data i get is as follow:

```
[
    {
     "model": "Galeria.imagen", 
     "pk": 20, 
     "fields": 
                {"image_width": 6000, 
                "image_height": 4000, 
                "fichero_imagen": "files/img/lucas-albuquerque-615558-unsplash.jpg", 
                "keyword": [17, 18]}
    }, 
    {
     "model": "Galeria.imagen", 
     "pk": 21, 
     "fields": 
                {"image_width": 5855, 
                 "image_height": 3860, 
                 "fichero_imagen": "files/img/freestocks-org-794156-unsplash.jpg", 
                 "keyword": [18]}
    }
]
```

I have tried things like:

- obj.data[0].pk
- obj.data[0][pk]
- obj.data[0].['pk']
- obj.data.pk[0]

and so on, but I always get undefined.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that _really_ the JSON? There are inconsistencies

Comment: Well, I generate it according to Django Docs about how to serialize objects so the JSON is generated by Django. Why it is wrong? Im new with JSON.

Comment: I'm not saying it is wrong, I'm saying that you show the root of your JSON data as an array (`[`), yet you access the parsed JSON as `obj.data`. So what does the _complete_ JSON string look like? So in the commented out console log, what do you get if you `console.log()` only `obj`?

Comment: try `obj.data[0]['pk']` no dot. Maybe `obj.data[0][0]['pk']`

Comment: Oh and it is not json is a python list of dictionaries.

Comment: @RedCricket. obj.data[0][0['pk']] returns undefined.

Comment: @RandyCasburn. console.log(obj) shows {data: "[{"model": "Galeria.imagen", "pk": 20, "fields": {…ocks-org-794156-unsplash.jpg", "keyword": [1 ...

Comment: Did you try `obj.data[0]['pk']`?

Comment: on success are you able to get the response in  the same format as you given in the question ?

Comment: Why are you casting your `JSONResponse` [( which is already a subclass of the `HttpResponse` class)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) into a `HttpResponse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're serializing your data into JSON twice. Once with `data = serializers.serialize('json', objects)` and again with `JsonResponse({'data': data})`. Creating the `JsonResponse` escapes the JSON from the first call turning the list into a big string.

You'll need to remove the nested `JsonResponse` and pass the JSON directly.

```
objects = process_speech(speech)
data = serializers.serialize('json', objects)
return HttpResponse(data)  # Pass the JSON direct to the HttpResponse
```

You'll then need to modify your Javascript so that it expects the top level object to be a list (no `data` property):

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = obj[0]['pk'];
```